# ¿Cómo hago para mostrar la cantidad de ese producto?

Tags: php, pdo

Código PHP:

```
    $consulta=("SELECT * FROM inventario where id_articulo='$articulo'");
        $conexion = mainModel::conectar();
        $datos2 = $conexion->query($consulta);
        $datos2 = $datos2->fetchAll();

    $cantidad_exist=$datos2['cantidad_existente'];
```

Solo quiero mostrar la cantidad del producto y me sale:

> Notice: Undefined index: cantidad_existente in C:\xampp\htdocs\SIEC\Modelo\inventarioModelo.php on line 116

El esquema de la base de datos es la siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE `inventario` (
 `id_articulo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `nombre_art` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `categoria_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `precio_unitario` float(11,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
 `cantidad_existente` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
 `descripcion` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `fecha_llegada` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id_articulo`),
 KEY `nombre_art` (`nombre_art`),
 KEY `categoria_id` (`categoria_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `inventario_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`categoria_id`) REFERENCES `dat_ref` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Deberías compartir el esquema de la tabla `inventario`. Puedes verla usando `SHOW CREATE TABLE inventario`.

Comment: Solo necesito mostrar la cantidad del producto seleccionado para hacer una comparacion

Comment: Ya lo agrege...

Comment: He redactado una respuesta explicando el problema que estás sufriendo. Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Comment: ¿Te puedo hacer una última edición con un consejo **MUY IMPORTANTE**? Por favor, **NUNCA** concatenes el contenido de una variable a una consulta SQL. Ese tipo de malas prácticas te provocan [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) asociados a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyección_SQL). En su lugar usa la función de escapado (como hago en la respuesta) o [consultas preparadas](https://www.php.net/es/pdo.prepared-statements).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función [PDOStatement::fetchAll()](https://php.net/es/pdostatement.fetchall) devuelve una matriz con todos los registros obtenidos o `false en caso de error, por lo que debes comprobar que:

- La consulta fue bien y no vale `false`.
- Que contiene algún registro usando `count()`.

Por ejemplo, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
/* Escapamos el contenido de $articulo para evitar inyección SQL */
$consulta=("
    SELECT *
    FROM inventario
    WHERE id_articulo = " . $conexion->quote($articulo)
);
$conexion = mainModel::conectar();
$datos2 = $conexion->query($consulta);
$datos2 = $datos2->fetchAll();
if ($datos2 !== false && count($datos2) > 0) {
    /* Obtenemos el precio del primer registro obtenido */
    $cantidad_exist = $datos2[0]['cantidad_existente'];
} else {
    die('No se encontró el registro');
}
```

Tu código podría sufrir los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) asociados a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL) debido a la forma en la que concatenas el contenido de una variable al código SQL.

He modificado la forma en la que haces la consulta SQL haciendo uso de la función [`PDO::quote()`](https://php.net/manual/es/pdo.quote), aunque te recomiendo que uses [consultas preparadas](https://www.php.net/es/pdo.prepared-statements).

Comment: Gracias Amigo :D...